GeoTIFF from HDF using Python's GDAL
Below is my code, and the output says translation complete, but for some reason, the output file is not appearing the output directory. Its' not getting saved.
from osgeo import gdal
# Define file paths and dataset
file_path = r'D:\MOPITT\2000\Apr\MOP03J-20000401-L3V5.9.3.he5'
dataset_path = 'HDFEOS/GRIDS/MOP03/Data_Fields/APrioriCOMixingRatioProfileDay'
output_path = r'D:\MOPITT\2000\Apr\gdaloutput.tif'

# Construct full path
full_path = f'HDF5:"{file_path}"://{dataset_path}'

# Open the dataset
dataset = gdal.Open(full_path)
if dataset:
    print("Dataset opened successfully.")
    print("Raster Size:", dataset.RasterXSize, "x", dataset.RasterYSize)
else:
    print("Failed to open the dataset.")

# Define kwargs
kwargs = {
    'format': 'GTiff',
    'outputSRS': '+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84',  # Adjust if needed
    'outputBounds': [0.0, -180.0, 360.0, 0.0],  # Adjust if needed
    'xRes': 1.0,
    'yRes': 1.0
}

# Translate the dataset
try:
    ds = gdal.Translate(output_path, full_path, **kwargs)
    ds = None
    print("Translation complete.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error during translation:", e)

I have tried installing gdal in multiple places. I ran the command with shell, and it worked. It didn't work with Python. I have installed gdal in conda forge, and using Jupyter notebook. I don't understand why it doesn't want to work no matter how much you try using Python.

The first thing to do is call gdal.UseExceptions() after importing gdal, otherwise the gdal python bindings don't throw exceptions: GDAL exceptions
